# Twitter Web Intents not firing 'tweet' event in Internet Explorer

Tags: twitter, callback

Old Problem - still no solution??

Using Twitter Web Intents I want to perform an action after the callback from Twitter (after a Tweet was successfully posted).
It works in all Browsers but not in IE (Versions >=8 tested). I recieve NOTHING in IE so the event is not firing.
I use following code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<script>
window.twttr = (function (d,s,id) {
var t, js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return; js=d.createElement(s); js.id=id;
js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
return window.twttr || (t = { _e: [], ready: function(f){ t._e.push(f) } });
}(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Test">Tweet</a></p>

<script>
twttr.ready(function(twttr) {       
twttr.events.bind('tweet', function (event) {
alert('Yes, yes');
console.log('TWEETED, mate');
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for help- need to get this to work.

Comment: this may help https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/3102

Comment: Doesn`t help. I`ve read it all (like many others). No solution to this problem.