# Get Twitter 'tweet' event for Web Intents dialog

Tags: javascript, events, twitter, webintents

My site allows each user to tweet to their profile using Web Intents.

I'd like to count the number of times each user tweeted through my site, as well as the date of the last tweet. In order to do so, all I need is to get determine whether or not the tweet happened, using the event response. I went through Twitter's API and found this strategy (excuse the coffeescript):

```
twttr.events.bind "tweet", (event) ->
  # do something
```

However, it doesn't seem to be firing. Ever. I know it [has some problems with IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21675298/twitter-web-intents-not-firing-tweet-event-in-internet-explorer), but I'm only using chrome, safari and FF.

Am I doing something wrong here? Does anyone know where that problem stems from?

Comment: are you running behind a web server? https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/4953

Comment: @michaeltruong, yes, I am - Apache. I think I was able to narrow it down to the cause - when loading the widgets.js file asynchronously, window.twttr returns undefined (and therefore cannot be used on the event bindings that follow. Could this be the problem?

Comment: yup, if twttr is undefined at the time of binding, then nothing will be bound. if you are attempting to bind on undefined, you should be getting an exception. have you checked the console?  @NYK .

Comment: yup, no exceptions.. 
I ended up using the browser event fired natively (postMessage). Not comfortable with posting it as the answer, because it's more a workaround than a solution, but I thought it'd be useful for others.